# difference between string valueof(char[]) and new string(char[])

Tags: java, arrays, string, fortify

The output for following print statement is same, is there any internal difference which is safe as per Privacy Violation: Heap Inspection

char[] ch ={'p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d'};

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(ch));

System.out.println(new String(ch));
```

Comment: When you made the effort to read the javadoc, what didn't you understand?

Comment: Asked this question having privacy violation in mind. there is tool called fortify which scan the entire application and generate issue report privacy violation heap inspection is one of them. For String.valueof it was showing the heap inspection problem but when I used new String(chat array) it got solved though there is no difference between so asked. comment appreciated @SotiriosDelimanolis

Answer (score 5):

There is no real difference because internal implementation of `valueOf` is the following:

```
public static String valueOf(char data[]) {
    return new String(data);
}
```

As you can see it calls directly `new String(data)`

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference

`valueOf` is static factory method which calls `String` constructor